# Parsing through HTML to extract data from table rows with beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to extract stock information from the NASDAQ website. I want to retrieve information specifically from the table rows on the HTML page but I am always getting an error (line 12).

```
    #import html-parser
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from requests import get

    url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/amzn' #AMZN is just an example
    response = get(url)

    #Create parse tree (BeautifulSoup Object)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find_all(class_= 'column span-1-of-2')

    table = data.find(class_= 'table-row') #This is where the error occurs
    print(table)
```

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: kindly tell us more about that specific table. and where it is

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the data from table rows.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

r = requests.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/")

print(r)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find('table',{'id':'indexTable', 'class':'floatL marginB5px'}).script.text
matches = re.findall(r'nasdaqHomeIndexChart.storeIndexInfo(.*);\r\n', data)
table_rows = [re.findall(r'\".*\"', row) for row in matches]
print(table_rows)
```

`table_rows` is list of lists containing table data.